# Can my son play Minecraft with his XBOX 360 friends with his XBOX One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

Since MS has introduced backward compatibility can my son connect with minecraft games being played on his friend's 360 with his XBOX one?  I purchased the gold membership solely for this purpose but my son gets a "Connection Lost" notice when attempting to join these games.  Before I chase my tail trying to resolve this, I want to make sure that what we are trying to do is even possible.  Thx

Comment: Advice: just play it on the PC, it's better anyway.

Comment: XD  so true, but a little harsh

Answer (score 12):

It is currently not possible.  Backwards compatibility is only for these games:

http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games

If MS makes the 360 version of Minecraft backwards compatible, it will be possible.  But then you'll have to buy the XBox 360 version of the game to play on your XBox One.

Answer (score -1):

**Now it is possible for everyone, check the link for supported games.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_games_compatible_with_Xbox_One

*The link includes all compatible games from the [official list](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games) with some extra notes and dates*